# In r, summary(variable) and mean(variable) output different means?

Tags: r, mean, summary

I'm working in R Studio with R version 4.2.2. I imported a data set from a csv file. In working with the data frame, I noticed that, for one variable. summary() and mean() output different results. The data are:

```r
> HDIEUR$`Gross national income (GNI) per capita`
 [1]  14131  51167  13158  53619  14257  18849  52293  15242  23079  30132  38745  60365  38048
[14]  49452  45937  14664  54534  29002  32789  55782  76169  42840  32803 146830  37931  84649
[27]  38884  14875     NA  20839  55979  15918  64660  33034  33155  30027  27166  52654  19123
[40]  30690  39746  38354  54489  66933  31033  13256  45225
```

The variable is numeric:

```r
> str(HDIEUR$`Gross national income (GNI) per capita`)
 num [1:47] 14131 51167 13158 53619 14257 ...
```

When I execute summary(), the output is:

```r
> summary(HDIEUR$`Gross national income (GNI) per capita`)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  13158   24101   37990   40272   52564  146830
```

When I execute mean(), the output is:

```r
> mean(HDIEUR$`Gross national income (GNI) per capita`)
[1] NA
```

What causes this anomalous behavior?

Comment: If there are any `NA` values in the variable `x`, then `mean(x)` will evaluate to `NA`, but `mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)` will calculate the mean of the valid responses, which is what `summary()` does.

Comment: Thank you.
Seems out that mean() and summary() would be asymmetrical.

Comment: Perhaps, I think the rationale is that if people are calculating a mean to be used in other contexts (i.e., inside another function), they're not using the `summary()` function.  And, that having this type of behaviour makes it explicit what R is doing and provides a check for your own work.  There is an [old thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-July/283499.html) on the R listserv where they talk about this. Also note, `summary()` also tells you how many `NA` values there are.

Answer (score 0):

There´s an NA value in your data, if you use the

```
mean(HDIEUR$`Gross national income (GNI) per capita`, na.rm=T)
```

argument, it should work!
Best,
Sebastian

Comment: Thank you. It still seems like bizarre behavior because summary() produces a numeric response.